# Why the object is not passed within the callback of the route handler of express.Router(), being exported from different module?

Tags: node.js, express

Entrypoint of my server is `publisher.js`. Its code is the following:

```
'use strict';

const publishingRoute = require('./routes/enqueue');

     . . . .
     . . . .

const PublishingServicePort = process.env.PUB_PORT || 4001;
const RabbitMQHostURL = process.env.RABBITMQ_AMQP_URL;
const RabbitMQQueueName = process.env.QUEUE;
const RabbitMQRoutingKey = process.env.ROUTING_KEY;
const RabbitMQExchange = process.env.EXCHANGE;

let rbmqChannel;
let rbmqConnection;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//initConnection() creates the TCP connection and confirm channel with the Broker. No error here
(async function initConnection() {
    rbmqConnection = await rbmqConnectionManager.connect(amqp, RabbitMQHostURL);
    rbmqChannel = await rbmqConnectionManager.createConfirmChannel(rbmqConnection);
})();


//Error Here: None of the parameter is passed to the callback function
app.use('/enqueue', publishingRoute.enqueueUser(rbmqChannel, RabbitMQQueueName, RabbitMQRoutingKey, RabbitMQExchange));



app.listen(PublishingServerPort , async () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PublishingServerPort }`);
})
```

`../routes/` contains modules, that handles the routes from the `publisher.js`. One of the routes's module is the `enqueue.js`. It enqueues JabberID of the users (JSON) into the RabbitMQ queue, through the Exchange. The following code are of `enqueue.js` module.

```
'use strict';

const router = require('express').Router();
const PublisherService = require('../services/rbmq-publisher');

export function enqueueUser(amqpChannel, queueName, routingKey, exchange) {
    //Error: No parameter has reached here. amqpChannel, queueName, routingKey, and exchange are undefined. I need all of them here.
    router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        const content = req.body.payload;
        await PublisherService.PublishPayload(amqpChannel, exchange, routingKey, content);

        res.status(200);
        res.send({
            "Message": "OK",
            "payloadEnqueued": content
        });
    });

    return router;
}
```

`rbmq-publisher.js` is the controller (module) for handling publishing/enqueuing into the RabbitMQ Exchange. The following code is of the `rbmq-publisher.js`

```
'use strict';    

const PublishPayload = async function(channel, exchange, routingKey, content) {
    //Error: None of the parameter has reached here. All of them are undefined.
    console.info(`[AMQP] : Publishing Message ...`);
    
    try {
        await channel.publish(exchange, routingKey, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(content)));
        console.log(`[AMQP SUCCESS]: JabberID Published`);
    }

    catch(exception) {
        //This is what is being shown in the console window. I have written the error below this code snippet
        console.error(`[AMQP ERROR]: ${exception}`);
    }
};

export {
    PublishPayload
};
```

Console windows shows the following error:

```
[AMQP ERROR]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined
```

None of the arguments from the `app.use()` has reached the callback function. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Well it looks like the `IIFE` that contains this `await rbmqConnectionManager.connect` is executed and completed after `app.use()`. Even though you have `await` inside the `IIFE`, node will continue to execute the other JS code first

Comment: @codemax Even if I call the initConnection() from the callback of app.listen(), it still throws the same error

Comment: Of course it throws the same error. You need to either make the `initConnection()` call synchronous/blocking before `app.use()` or place `app.use()` inside `initConnection()`. I can't guarantee placing `app.use()` inside `initConnection()`works, but you can give it a try

Comment: @codemax synchronizing functions by promises chaining worked. Thanks :)